# How to get an Conda env to use Python 3.8?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I installed Anaconda today on my new mac. I want to run my Python code in a conda env called gliders with Python 3.8. This is how I created my new env:

`conda create -n gliders python=3.8 anaconda`

But after I activate the env and run `python --version` it says Python 2.7.10

I've also tried remove the env and recreating it with these different attempts:
`conda create -n gliders python=3.8` and
`conda create -n gliders python=3`

Comment: You *must* `init`ialize your shell (only once) so that conda can work. Do you see a `(gliders)` at the beginning of the shell line after `activate`ing?

Comment: Yes it says (gliders) at the beginning of the shell line